# XSLT 3.0 - replace number characters with number-string representations

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to use xslt to create an xml data-set, and currently facing with problem that i am trying to set some invalid element names,3RD_RACK,3DATA_VIEW and what i've tried was to use :

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(current()/@name), translate(current()/@name), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_', ''), '_')"/>
```

which replaces `3RD_RACK -> _RD_RACK`

and all other numbers in data-set like:

```
PROGRAMMDAUERPROGRAM1 -> PROGRAMMDAUERPROGRAM
ENERGY_CLASS_2010 -> ENERGY_CLASS__
```

What i came into my mind is to replace all numbers with their string representations to faciliate with xml validation such as :

1 -> one
2 -> two

So in the end my input becomes :

```
3RD_RACK -> threeRD_RACK, ENERGY_CLASS_twozeroonezero, PROGRAMMDAUERPROGRAMone
```

But, i couldn't achive my goal by trying:

```
    <xsl:variable name="MyMap" select="
            map { 
            '1' : 'one', 
            '2' : 'two',
            '3' : 'three',
            '4' : 'four',
            '5' : 'five',
            '6' : 'six', 
            '7' : 'seven',
            '8' : 'eight',
            '9' : 'nine'}">
        </xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$MyMap(current()/@name)"/>
```

returns only numbers, so can someone help me how i can translate only numbers occured in string ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to replace only the first character of the string, if it is a digit?

Comment: I would first check `not(current()/@name castable as xs:NCName)` as otherwise you don't have to replace anything and can just use the value. As for a strategy to replace digits, I agree with Michael that you only need to replace the first character if it is a digit. Breaking up that string can be done all sorts of ways, using substring, using analyze-string, using string-to-codepoints.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, normally i've implemented same technique that Michael has been suggested, and currently this covers me and i can create my dataset. But; i just wonder how this could be done then asked here that how to achieve this goal easily. Would be helpful for other kind of requirements as well.

Comment: It is not necessary to alter (replace) any digits. If I have your problem, I will simply prepend 'N' in front of any string that starts with a digit -- and this is significantly easier to accomplish. Do let me know if you want me to post an answer with this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that uses the `analyze-string` function from XPath 3 to replace any ASCII digit with the name from the map:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:variable name="MyMap" select="
            map { 
            '0' : 'zero',
            '1' : 'one', 
            '2' : 'two',
            '3' : 'three',
            '4' : 'four',
            '5' : 'five',
            '6' : 'six', 
            '7' : 'seven',
            '8' : 'eight',
            '9' : 'nine'}">
        </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:param name="names"
    as="xs:string*"
    select="'3RD_RACK', 'ENERGY_CLASS_2010', 'PROGRAMMDAUERPROGRAM1'"/>

  <xsl:variable name="converted-names"
    as="xs:string*"
    select="$names ! string-join(analyze-string(., '[0-9]')/*/(if (self::*:match) then $MyMap(.) else string()))"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of 
        select="$converted-names" separator="&#10;"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
threeRD_RACK
ENERGY_CLASS_twozeroonezero
PROGRAMMDAUERPROGRAMone
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ8LVj/2

Comment: especially, it is good that when using it combined with "not(current()/@name castable as xs:NCName)", by simply checking <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not(current()/@name castable as xs:NCName)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="current()/@name ! string-join(analyze-string(., '[0-9]')/*/(if (self::*:match) then $MyMap(.) else string()))"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current()/@name"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose> thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution would be to code the digits using other characters. Then you could do simply something like:

```
<xsl:element name="{translate(@name, '1234567890', 'αβγδεζηθικλμνξο')}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:element>
```

This has the further advantage of being able to restore the original name (assuming it did not contain any of the characters used for the replacement). Using your method, it's impossible to tell if the original was `"1d"` or `"oned"`.

---

Note also that your method could be implemented in the old-fashioned XSLT 1.0 way:

```
<xsl:variable name="name">
    <xsl:variable name="char1" select="substring(@name, 1, 1)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$char1='0'">zero</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$char1='1'">one</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$char1='2'">two</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$char1='3'">three</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$char1='4'">four</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$char1='5'">five</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$char1='6'">six</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$char1='7'">seven</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$char1='8'">eight</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$char1='9'">nine</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$char1"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(@name, 2)"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:element name="{$name}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:element>
```

It doesn't seem much more verbose than XSLT 3.0.

---

**Added:**

I forgot to mention the most important thing: there are other ways a string can fail to conform to the [XML name specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Name). If you cannot be sure that the provided name is a valid XML element name, then the most proper thing to do would be:

```
<elem name="{@name}">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
</elem>
```

This is the simplest and at the same time, the safest, solution.